# react native map issue

Tags: ios, react-native

My app gives me error when I import MapView on react nativ

Here is my code:

```
    `import MapView from 'react-native-maps'`
```

just importing it like that gives me an erorr[image]

Here is my dpendency:

```js
 "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.6.1",
    "react-native": "0.57.7",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.22.1",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.6"
  },
```

```js
Opening /Users/Desktop/snl/reactNative/ChatApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js with /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ../../index.js ▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓ 100.0% (1/1), done.

 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ../../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1)::1 - - [09/Dec/2018:08:42:21 +0000] "GET /index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "ChatApp/1 CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/17.7.0"
::1 - - [09/Dec/2018:08:42:24 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "ChatApp/1 CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/17.7.0"
::1 - - [09/Dec/2018:08:42:25 +0000] "POST /symbolicate HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "ChatApp/1 CFNetwork/975.0.3 Darwin/17.7.0"
^[[1;2D
```

Comment: What is the output on the terminal?

Comment: @UzairA. i have updated the output of the terminal